# How to play video through url by fetching from json file in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

In the image url i have been using mpd file url and provided it with a video widget in my dart file.

[image: code as image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask check this then edit question

Comment: You will need to be more precise. what did you try so far? what *can* you do, and where are you stuck and need help?